# SwiftUI | File found on simulator but not on iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a connection between my program and a database located in `/Documents` of the app. When the code is built using on the simulator, it successfully opens the database; however, when I run the code on an iOS device, it can't find the file.

This is the code that I use:

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        .documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true
    ).first!
    
    let db = try! Connection("\(path)/Database.db")
```

These are the contents of the variable `path` when I run the code on the simulator:

```
/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EFD14A1B-7207-4840-9ACE-8E44A269CC70/data/Containers/Data/Application/58D150B9-E242-4857-B06C-DA28C88A26D0/Documents
```

And these are the contents of the variable `path` when I run the code on an iOS device:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4EC93D76-4E99-4552-855A-48C1D9346449/Documents
```

Xcode version: 12.0

iOS device: iPhone X

iOS version: 14.1

**Edit**
I tried to use this code to copy the database from the app bundle to the document directory, but it gives the error `Unable to copy file`:

```
copyFileToDocumentsFolder(nameForFile: "Database", extForFile: "db")


func copyFileToDocumentsFolder(nameForFile: String, extForFile: String) {

    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let destURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(nameForFile).appendingPathExtension(extForFile)
    guard let sourceURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: nameForFile, withExtension: extForFile)
        else {
            print("Source File not found.")
            return
    }
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItem(at: sourceURL, to: destURL)
        } catch {
            print("Unable to copy file")
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you copy the database from the Bundle to the document directory?

Comment: @LeoDabus Is there a code I can use to do this?

Comment: See my update please

Comment: Version 3.0.0 GM is updated! All versions 1, 2 and 3 are working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned in your last question the Bundle is read-only. you need to move/copy your database to another directory that you can read/write to it. If you don't want the user to have access to the file you should copy it to that application support directory:

```
extension URL {
    static let database: URL = {
        let applicationSupport = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let bundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "company name"
        let subDirectory = applicationSupport.appendingPathComponent(bundleID, isDirectory: true)

        let destination = subDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Database.db")
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destination.path) {

            let source = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Database", withExtension: "db")!
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: subDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                print("directory created")
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: source, to: destination)
                print("file copied successfully")
            } catch {
                print("Unable to copy file. return the bundle read-only version")
                return source
            }
        }
        print("database found return app suport database read-write url")
        return destination
    }()
}
```

---

```
let dbURL = URL.database
```

Comment: When I ran this code, it skipped the if statement and went straight to print "database found return app suport database read-write url".

Comment: You probably had already copied the dabase.It will not overwrite it. I mean it will only copy the database the first time you access this property.

Comment: It now works on the simulator, but again when I run it on an iOS device, the app can't find the file in the bundle so it creates a new empty file which is then copied onto the directory. If the file exists when ran in the simulator, it should exist on the iOS device no?

Comment: Why don't you get the file from the simulator and manually copy it to your project bundle? this way you make sure you have a working version of the database to start with in your project. The first time you run the app it will be copied to the app support folder.

Comment: Make sure to check mark "copy if needed" when you drag it into your project

Answer (score 2):

**You can use url or path:** with this codes you get the address of your data base, but you have to have your database file already there when your app use this address to find your databace! if you use this address, without having real file there, your app will crash. So if you have problem about copying your databace file let me know!

**Version: 1.0.0**

```
let appBaseURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].standardizedFileURL
let databaseURL = appBaseURL.appendingPathComponent("Database").appendingPathExtension("db").standardizedFileURL
let databasePath = databaseURL.path
```

**Update Version: 2.0.0**

**This codes down are the most simplest and cleanest code about copy and paste on planet Earth for Swift and SwiftUI! You can not find better than this:**

```
// If you want see your file in device or give user access to the file do this 2 steps:
// 1 - add this one ("Application supports iTunes file sharing" -> Yes) from (info.plist)
// 2 -add this one ("Supports opening documents in place" -> Yes) from (info.plist)
                    
let fileName = "omid"
let fileExtension = "jpeg"
                        
 let appBaseURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].standardizedFileURL
         let pasteFileURL = appBaseURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension(fileExtension).standardizedFileURL

          let copyFileURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension(fileExtension).standardizedFileURL
                    
        
                    
                    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appBaseURL.path)
                    {
                        print("appBaseFolder already exists!")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        do{ try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: appBaseURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil); print("appBaseFolder successfully created!") }
                        catch{ print("Error in creating appBaseFolder!") }
                    }
                    
        
                    
                    if      FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pasteFileURL.path)
                    {
                        print("The selected file already exists!")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        do{ try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: copyFileURL, to: pasteFileURL); print("The selected file successfully copied!") }
                        catch { print("Error with copying selected file!") }
                    }
```

**Version: 3.0.0 (The GM Version)**

```
//▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲
// If you want see your file in device or give user access to the file do this 2 steps:
// 1 - add this one ("Application supports iTunes file sharing" -> Yes) from (info.plist)
// 2 - add this one ("Supports opening documents in place" -> Yes) from (info.plist)
//...........................................................
let fileName = "omid"
let fileExtension = "jpeg"
//...........................................................
let appBaseURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].standardizedFileURL
let pasteFileURL = appBaseURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension(fileExtension).standardizedFileURL
let copyFileURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension(fileExtension).standardizedFileURL
//▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼




//...........................................................
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appBaseURL.path)
{
    print("appBaseFolder already exists!")
}
else
{
    do{ try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: appBaseURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil); print("appBaseFolder successfully created!") }
    catch{ print("Error in creating appBaseFolder!") }
}
//...........................................................



//...........................................................
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: copyFileURL.path)
{
    //...........................................................
    if      FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pasteFileURL.path)
    {
        print("The selected file already exists!")
    }
    else
    {
        do{ try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: copyFileURL, to: pasteFileURL); print("The selected file successfully copied!") }
        catch { print("Error with copying selected file!") }
    }
    //...........................................................
}
else
{
    print("The selected file not exists for copy Action!") 
}
//...........................................................
```

Comment: how can I copy my database into the document directory?

Comment: it depend where is your db, is it in device or is it inside app?

Comment: The database is inside the app, I've edited my question to show a code I tried to use to copy the database from the app bundle to the document directory.

Comment: No problem, give me time to update my Answer with copying function for you

Comment: @DiegoGonzalez , you should give your file name instead of "Omid", also "db" instead of "jpeg"

Comment: Why would OP give access to the user to the database? Btw what "Supports opening documents in place" has to do with what is being asked here? And what is the purpose of standardizedFileURL here as well? This will only make OP more confuse than he is already.

Comment: ***If you want see your file in device or give user access to the file do this 2 steps*** it can be used for copying photo as my code example! I wanted cover every thing here! but for dataBase No need!

Comment: ***standardizedFileURL*** is very important, without using that app could possibly crashed because of: /var/mobile/. .   and  /Users/xxxx/ . . I have lots of experience about ***standardizedFileURL*** IT IS A MUST

Comment: @Omid not it is not. This is definitely not needed to move/copy a file from the Bundle.

Comment: @LeoDabus It was not my Idea copy file from Bundle, he wanted like that see his comment, I did it for him

Comment: It is not an option. Bundle is read-only. I told him that he can not modify the database inside the bundle. Btw he didn't even know that when copying the file to his project it would be located there. He thought it would be inside the documents folder

Comment: @LeoDabus, I know that, that is why i asked him where is your file to copy, and he answered ***"The database is inside the app"*** I think he has just Empty dataBase, and he just copy it and modify it on device not on Bundle hopefully! LoL

Answer (score 0):

The Mac (and by extension the Simulator) has a case-insensitive file system. iOS has a case-sensitive file system. If it's working on the simulator, but not the device, I expect the capitalization of your database filename is incorrect. The most likely mistake would be that it's `database.db` rather than `Database.db`.