# Update Json File Under Document Directory

Tags: json, swift

I have local Json file in app bundle.

Existing Json file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1001,
        "key1": "key1Value",
        "key2": "key2Value",
    },
    {
        "id": 1002,
        "key1": "key1Value",
        "key2": "key2Value",
    },
    {
        "id": 1003,
        "key1": "key1Value",
        "key2": "key2Value",
    },
]
```

I copy that Json to Document directory with following code:

```
let vehicleInfo: [Vehicle] = readJSON("vehicleInfo.json")
func readJSON<T: Codable>(_ named: String) -> T {
    if let resPath = Bundle.main.resourcePath {
        do {
            let dirContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: resPath)
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
            let filteredFiles = dirContents.filter{ $0.contains(".json")}
            for fileName in filteredFiles {
                if let documentsURL = documentsURL {
                    let sourceURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                    let destURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sourceURL, to: destURL)
                        print("Save to documents")
                    } catch {
                        print("ERROR FileManager.default.copyItem:: ", error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch { print("ERRIR 2", error) }
    }
    let data: Data
    do {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default
            .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("vehicleInfo.json")
        
        data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        let foo = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)            
        return foo
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't find  in main bundle.")
    }
}
```

User updates some values(only `key2`'s value can be change by the user) of Json.

User updated Json file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1001,
        "key1": "key1Value",
        "key2": "key2ValueChanged",
    },
    {
        "id": 1002,
        "key1": "key1Value",
        "key2": "key2ValueChanged",
    },
    {
        "id": 1003,
        "key1": "key1Value",
        "key2": "key2ValueChanged",
    },
]
```

Json update code:

```
do {
    let fileURL = try FileManager.default
        .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent("vehicleInfo.json")
    
    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(self.userData.vehicles)
    
    try jsonData.write(to: fileURL)
} catch {
    print("an error happened while creating the file", error)
}
```

Now I will update my app with new Json file that has some new keys and objects.

I have 2 goals:

1 - Copy the new Json file into the Document folder with the same name.

2 - Copy the existing `key2`'s values to new Json file's `key2`.

When user updates the app, Document folder should has the following Json file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1001,
        "key1": "key1Value",
        "key2": "key2ValueChanged",
        "key3": "key3Value",
    },
    {
        "id": 1002,
        "key1": "key1Value",
        "key2": "key2ValueChanged",
        "key3": "key3Value",
    },
    {
        "id": 1003,
        "key1": "key1Value",
        "key2": "key2ValueChanged",
        "key3": "key3Value",
    },
    {
        "id": 1004,
        "key1": "key1Value",
        "key2": "key2ValueChanged",
        "key3": "key3Value",
    }
]
```

*How can I copy the new Json file to the Document directory and copy existing Json file's `key2` values to new Json file?*

Comment: Why would you need to list the contents of your bundle resource folder? There is no guarantee that your file will be located there. What you should use is `let vehicleInfoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "vehicleInfo", withExtension: "json")!`

Comment: Btw you should use the `ApplicationSupportDirectory` instead of the `DocumentDirectory`
 for this

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No, `key3` will have its own value.

Comment: @LeoDabus User updates the Json file and there is no way to update the file under bundle resource If I am not wrong. Also, what is the advantage of the `ApplicationSupportDirectory`?

Comment: It is not about advantage. It depends if you would like the user to have direct access to the resource or not.

Comment: @ilvthsgm  yes the bundle is read only. You just need to copy it to the ApplicationSupportDirectory at the first access. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64754020/2303865

Comment: To update the array efficiently take a look at [`difference(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3200715-difference)

Comment: @vadian I dont think OP needs this. OP just need to copy/move the file once and always update the file at the new location when modified

Comment: @LeoDabus I see that `ApplicationSupportDirectory` cannot be looked by the user. As you said, I believe it's better the use `ApplicationSupportDirectory` instead of  `DocumentDirectory`.

Comment: @ilvthsgm just note that it is recommended to create a subdirectory there to store your files https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: @vadian seems right . I need to check the difference between old Json file and new Json file to copy the old Json file's `key2` values to new Json file.

Comment: **Use this directory to store all app data files except those associated with the user’s documents. For example, you might use this directory to store app-created data files, configuration files, templates, or other fixed or modifiable resources that are managed by the app. An app might use this directory to store a modifiable copy of resources contained initially in the app’s bundle. A game might use this directory to store new levels purchased by the user and downloaded from a server.**

Comment: **All content in this directory should be placed in a custom subdirectory whose name is that of your app’s bundle identifier or your company.
In iOS, the contents of this directory are backed up by iTunes and iCloud.**

Comment: @ilvthsgm No. Just write the whole new json file when modified. That method is normally used to check differences like the directory contents (if the user deletes a file or change the sort criteria) and update the UI

Comment: @LeoDabus When user update the app with new Json file, how user can see his/her previously  updated `key2` values in the app? I miss that point I guess.

Comment: This is simple. It all depends on your goal. You can check fetch the value from your old json file if it exists and update the new one with the value. The question regarding the key2 as it stands is too vague but you can easily update the new json with the old value if needed.

Comment: The question is still persist. I cannot loop over the Json and cannot get the old `key2` value. Can you show me how can I update the new Json file with the old `key2` values?